# Проверить возможность составления слова по алфавиту

Tags: c#, массивы, pascal

Здравствуйте, есть два текстовых файла, первый содержит:

```
АвтарВаВук
атк
яхъу
рат
```

`АвтарВаВук` - алфавит, всё, что ниже - слова.

Второй файл для вывода.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести во второй файл все слова из первого, которые можно составить, используя алфавит. Сложность заключается в том, что буквы могут повторяться. Написал код на паскале, но он получился очень громоздким и неэффективным по использованию памяти. Посоветуйте более упрощённый алгоритм на паскале или C#. Спасибо.

```
program Dictionary;

var 
    alphabet,
    tempAlphabet: array ['А'..'я'] of integer;
    someWord: string;
    input, output: text;
    ch: char;
    i: integer;
    flag: boolean;

begin
    assign(input, 'input.txt');
    reset(input);

    assign(output, 'output.txt');
    rewrite(output);

    while not(eoln(input)) do
    begin
        read(input, ch);
        inc(alphabet[ch]);
    end;
    readln(input); // переход на следующую строку

    tempAlphabet:=alphabet;

    while not(eof(input)) do 
    begin
        readln(input, someWord);

        for i:=1 to length(someWord) do
            for ch:= 'А' to 'я' do 
                if (someWord[i] = ch) and (alphabet[ch]>0) then
                begin                 
                    if (i = 1) and (ch = someWord[1]) 
                        then flag:=true; 

                    if (flag) then
                    begin  
                        dec(alphabet[ch]);   
                        write(output, ch);   
                    end
                    else break; 
                end;

                if (flag) 
                    then writeln(output);

                alphabet:=tempAlphabet;
                flag:=false;
    end;

    close(input);
    close(output);
end.
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код, чтобы он влезал по ширине

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В класс добавляете:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

И дальше хоть в static void Main(string[] args), хоть куда вам надо:

```
  var input = File.ReadAllLines("in.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

  // Загрузка алфавита.
  var alpha = input[0].ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray();

  var outList = new List<string>();
  for (var i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
  {
    var line = input[i];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && line.All(c => alpha.Contains(c)))
      outList.Add(line);
  }

  // Запись.
  File.WriteAllLines("out.txt", outList, Encoding.UTF8);
```