# Вывести слова, удовлетворяющие алфавиту

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, pascal

Есть два файла: input.txt и output.txt

Допустим, input.txt содержит:

```
Аа АА БЕВ бк бев бк
Абев
АААа
бк
бкбк
бкбкбк
```

Тогда output.txt будет содержать:

```
АААа
бк
бкбк
```

Первая строчка в input.txt - алфавит, ниже указаны слова.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы проверить все слова на возможность составления, используя алфавит, при этом буква алфавита может использоваться при составлении слова столько раз, сколько её копий есть в алфавите. Например, буква "бк" может использоваться один или два раза, но не три.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм решения этой задачи (на русском, C#, Pascal).

Большое спасибо за подсказки. Это задание от предыдущего отличается некоторыми условиями, которые в итоге значительно изменили код программы. Написал возможное решение, опираясь на ответ в предыдущем подобном задании:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Dictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
            var alphabet = input[0].Split(' ');
            var outList = new List<string>();

            for (var i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                var word = input[i];

                foreach (var el in alphabet)
                    word = new Regex(el).Replace(word, " ", 1);

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word)) outList.Add(input[i]);                    
            }

            File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", outList, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь не решаю учебные задачи за автора, не тот ресурс. Покажите что вы сделали и задайте конкретный вопрос по месту, которое вызвало затруднения.

Comment: На русском: полный перебор :)

Comment: _Существенно_ лучше полного перебора не получится, т. к. при достаточно плохом алфавите можно добиться серьёзного бектрекинга.

Comment: @VladD ха ха :) точно, только заметила :) .

Comment: А что значит перебором? Для начала не понятно, есть ли задача самому организовать поиск подстроки в строке - тогда быстрее  поиска перебором получится (ну вы знаете алгоритмы из гугля :) ) и совсем другое дело если можно использовать библиотеки, строки уже готовые.

Comment: @Mira: Ну, какой-нибудь брутфорс. В каждый момент пробовать добавить одну из строк алфавита, чтобы «продвинуться» в строке. Если их можно добавить несколько, то рассмотреть все случаи. Длинно и скучно, по идее.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474047 Есть в чем то отличие от этого вопроса?

Comment: @Monk предположительно -- только то, что отдельные *"символы"* алфавита могут состоять из нескольких символов.

Comment: @D-side а, точно, есть в условии. Ну, если автор умеет писать на C# - доделать несложно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверить возможность составления слова по алфавиту](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474047/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: @tutankhamun: вопросы похожи, но в этой вариации "буквы" многосимвольные, и есть ограничение на кол-во повторений.

Comment: мета: вопрос по теме и достаточно ясный, чтобы ответ дать. Не нужно использовать эти причины, чтобы закрывать вопрос -- для отсутствия усилий со стороны автора существует голосование: голосуйте  «против», если вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

загоните алфавит в строку(удалив пробелы, хотя можно и не удалять)
Берете слово, и копию строки алфавита
Перебираете буквы слова циклом, ищите в строке алфавита с удалением найденной буквы из копии алфавита. Если очередную букву слова не нашел в алфавите то слово отфильтровывается оно не подходит.
И так далее со всеми словами.

Comment: Не понятно чем мой вариант не понравился

Comment: Пробелы разделяют отдельные "буквы алфавита", и если их игнорировать, всё взорвётся. Соответственно, совершенно не учтён возможный сценарий, когда одна буква является префиксом другой. Почти уверен, что в наборе тестов такой пример имеется :) Ну и в целом ответ "высокоуровневый", но изложен совершенно без структуры. Даже изложение алгоритма в виде псевдокода было бы куда нагляднее.

Comment: Не пойму "Пробелы разделяют отдельные "буквы алфавита", и если их игнорировать, всё взорвётся. " - это как ?

Comment: Так что нужно было код написать ? эт задача для школьников

Comment: АА может я не правильно понял вопрос. Получается буква может быть несколькими символами ?

Comment: Если это так тогда можно рекурсией сделать

Comment: Да, несколькими. Да, код, но "псевдокод". В псевдокоде можно использовать совсем абстрактные операторы, которые всё ещё не дают готового решения, но позволяют лучше проследить структуру алгоритма.

Comment: Ну псевдо понятно что можно. Вообще задача интересная. но алгоритм явный по-моему один

Comment: Хотел поставить себе минус, но говорит что нельзя самому себе :)

Comment: А зачем? Вы-то как раз можете свой ответ отредактировать так, чтобы не хотелось себе ставить минус. Да и другие (я) могут пересмотреть своё мнение.